# Javascript Date Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's some problem with the dates, the expected result should be 1st the user should input the the .start_date field, the .end_date field should change according to the .days field. How the things is the date can change but not correctly.
For instance, today is the 27th June, when the .days field is set to 1, the .end_date field should be 28th June. However, the result turns out to be 27th June. What's the problem with the code. Thank you.

```js
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  $(".addSkip").click(function() {
    // row instance to use `find()` for the other input classes
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

    var date = new Date($row.find(".start_date").val()),
      days = parseInt($row.find(".days").val(), 10);

    if (!isNaN(date.getTime())) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

      $row.find(".end_date").val(date.toInputFormat());
    } else {
      alert("Invalid Date");
    }
  });

  Date.prototype.toInputFormat = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd = this.getDate().toString();
    return yyyy + "-" + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[0] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]); // padding
  };
})
(jQuery, this, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <input type="button" size="10" value="confirm date" class="addSkip"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date"  \> </td>
  <td><input type="text" size="3" name="skip[]" class="days" \> </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is your problem on the PHP side or Javascript side? You might want to create a [mcve] cutting out whichever language isn't relevant.

Comment: i think it's on the javascript side, as my php works fine

Comment: In that case, update your question and replace the PHP with a sample of the data that should be there. Then we can run your snippet.

Comment: And please, post all the relevant HTML. There is no `.days`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having this issue because you are in a timezone with minus hours from UTC.

I just added `+" 0:00:00"` to the `new Date()` object creation... And it fixed it.

```
var date = new Date($row.find(".start_date").val()+" 0:00:00")
```

See it in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EXbKmW?editors=1011).

Answer (score 2):

While the answer above solves the problem and works, I'd advice against using dates that way.

What if your time zone changes ? What if someone connects from a different time zone ?

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) for that.

Comment: You should read their docs since its all explained there with better examples than I could provide. Also there is quite a lot of information and troubleshooting on stackoverflow about it.   [moment.js docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)/[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=moment+js)